# Spring + Tomcat - Disable prepended app module name in form-login

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, cuba-platform

In our Spring security XML file, I have a `form-login` configuration tag:

```
<form-login always-use-default-target="true" 
        authentication-failure-url="/" 
        default-target-url="/bo/bo" 
        login-page="/" 
        login-processing-url="/login" 
        password-parameter="password" 
        username-parameter="login"/>
```

My app is called "myapp", and it's accessible from `localhost:8080/myapp`.

When I successfully login, it goes to `localhost:8080/myapp/bo/bo`, which is expected.

However, now I have a domain (say `mywebsite.com`) that points to  `ip:port/myapp` on Tomcat, and what happens now is that when I login from `mywebsite.com`, it resolves into `ip:port/myapp/myapp/bo/bo`, and you can see the double app name(myapp) in the path. The first myapp is from domain DNS redirect setting(it has to be there to run in Tomcat), and the second myapp seems somehow from default-target-url in form-login Spring security XML.

How could I disable this behavior and get the URL resolve right to `ip:port/myapp/bo/bo`?

[I'm CUBA-Platform which build around Spring framework.]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this question is already answered here: https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/change-cuba-development-mode-to-production-mode-to-get-rid-of-auto-prepended-app-portal-in-url/2678

In short, deploy your portal application as ROOT application to tomcat. It means that you should rename tomcat/webapps/app-portal folder to tomcat/webapps/ROOT so your application will be deployed to /.

After that set cuba.webContextName in tomcat/conf/ROOT/local.app.properties

```
cuba.webContextName = /
```

And your portal will be accessible at http://domain.domain-zone/

Do not change the application code for this / deployment, just tune app settings.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to answer my own question. My father was the one who asked that question; we followed the answer and it worked. I'll upvote yours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @YuriyArtamonov from CUBA for answering the question!

As discussed here: https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/change-cuba-development-mode-to-production-mode-to-get-rid-of-auto-prepended-app-portal-in-url/2678/3

> Deploy your portal application as ROOT application to tomcat. It means that you should rename tomcat/webapps/app-portal folder ro tomcat/webapps/ROOT so your application will be deployed to /.
>
> After that set cuba.webContextName in tomcat/conf/app-portal/local.app.properties
>
> cuba.webContextName = /
>   And your portal will be accessible at http://domain.domain-zone/
>
> Do not change the application code for this / deployment, just tune app settings. That should be enough.